# Installing mono/fiddler on mac

Tags: c#, macos, mono, fiddler

I have been trying to install Fiddler on mac on several different Mac machines and on each machine I get a different error message, but none of them work. After install Mono via the Mac installer, and running `$ mono Fiddler.exe`, I get something like the following:

```
$ mono Fiddler.exe
WARNING: The Carbon driver has not been ported to 64bits, and very few parts of Windows.Forms will work properly, or at all

=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Is this a known issue with Mac/Fiddler, and if so, are there any possible ways to install Fiddler on Mac? The OS I am on is Mojave (10.14.6). Charles works fine, so I think it's related to `mono` more than `fiddler`.

Comment: @LexLi which one do you mean? https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler-osx-beta

Comment: Sounds like Telerik decided to hide it in a different page, https://www.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere

Comment: Fiddler for OSX is rather unstable as it's based on a problematic WinForms port for Mono. As @LexLi suggested, try to use [Fiddler Everywhere](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere) if possible. It's a cross-platform Electron app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this :  mono --arch=32 Fiddler.exe